# How can I link, dynamically, to an account profile / reputation?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, flair

I would like to know if there any way to put a link to my reputation on Stack Overflow to other sites.

I want to put an image similar to the following one, but the image should not be static, which means that if the user gains reputation, then the image should shown the change.

[image: User reputation on Stack Overflow]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are looking for "flair". Its code is available under the "flair" tab in your SO account profile.